# Jsoup: <div> within an <a>

Tags: html, html-parsing, jsoup

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-a-anchor-ever-correct/1828032#1828032):

> HTML 4.01 specifies that <a> elements
>   may only contain inline elements. A
>   <div> is a block element, so it may
>   not appear inside an <a>.

But...

> HTML5 allows <a> elements to contain
>   blocks.

Well, I just tried selecting a `<div class="m">` within an `<a>` block, using:

```
Elements elems = a.select("m");
```

and elmes returns empty, despite the div being there.

So I am thinking: Either I am not using the correct syntax for selecting a div within an a or... Jsoup doesn't support this HTML5-only feature?

What is the right Jsoup syntax for selecting a `div` within an `a`?

**Update**: I just tried

```
Elements elems = a.getElementsByClass("m");
```

And Jsoup had no problems with it (i.e. it returns the correct number of such divs within a).

So my question now is: Why?

Why does `a.getElementsByClass("m")` work whereas `a.select("m")` doesn't?

**Update**: I just tried, per @Delan Azabani's suggestion:

```
Elements elems = a.select(".m");
```

and it worked. So basically the `a.select()` works but I was missing the `.` in front of the class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select` function takes a selector. If you pass `'m'` as the argument, it'll try to find `m` elements that are children of the `a` element. You need to pass `'.m'` as the argument, which will find elements with the `m` class under the `a` element.

Comment: Did you mean `a.select(".m");` instead of `a.select("m");`? I am going to try this now and will report back.

Comment: Indeed, `a.select(".m");` worked per your suggestion. +1 and accepting.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of jsoup (1.5.2) does support `div` tags nested within `a` tags.

In situations like this I suggest printing out the parse tree, to ensure that jsoup has parsed the HTML like you expect, or if it hasn't to know what the correct selector to use.

E.g.:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<a href='./'><div class=m>Check</div></a>");
System.out.println("Parse tree:\n" + doc);
Elements divs = doc.select("a .m");
System.out.println("\nDiv in A:\n" + divs);
```

Gives:

```
Parse tree:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a href="./">
   <div class="m">
    Check
   </div></a>
 </body>
</html>

Div in A:
<div class="m">
 Check
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks to a tip from @BalusC I regularly print the parse tree whenever I encounter an unexpected result. Still, I noticed that you used `doc.select()` whereas I am using `a.select()` (where 'a' is the already successfully extracted anchor element). I have no problem using `doc.select()` where `m` is prefixed by `div.`. I am trying to figure out the exact rules of the syntax for `a.select()`. +1.

Comment: element.select() is the same as doc.select(), but it only looks down from the element it was initialised on. (A Document extends Element).